RabbitMQ's status shows Stopped and cannot be started
RabbitMQ log prompts：
enter image description here
And when I enter "rabbitmqctl status" prompt in the sbin folder:
enter image description here
The web address where I got help:Unable to start RabbitMq Service after uninstalling and then Re-installing RabbitMQ
I once deleted the RabbitMQ service in the task manager. Through the prompts of netizens, I regained it after operating in the registry editor.
My first language is not English, so I used Google Translate for the previous description. If there is any further information required I can provide it.
